# Get dynamic controls and text in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a Repeater which loads some data from a SQL database

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Button ID="AnswerSubmit" runat="server" Text="Insert"/>
```

In code behind, i assign to get the questions on another button click to load and bind the Repeater. In ItemDataBound i find the controls and assign the questions to the label.

How should i get the answers that the user enters and store the ID of the question with the answer they enter in a button click event?

At first, I tried this in the button click event

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater.Items)
{
    Label QuestionLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("QuestionLabel");
}
```

but it couldnt find the `QuestionLabel`. Looking at the page source i believe thats due to the label having a different value (QuestionLabel_0, QuestionLabel_1 etc), so struggling to find a way to approach this?

Edit

```
    protected void QuestionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater.DataSource = QuestionsByID(ID);
        Repeater.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve probably you don t even need .net controls in repeater. Just try to use html elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179938/asp-net-how-to-access-repeater-generated-form-input-elements)

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater.Items)
{
  if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item 
        || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    { 
      Label QuestionLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("QuestionLabel");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i saw that but the QuestionLabel is always null under the button click event?

Comment: Can you post your code where makes the bind of the data?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: In AnswerSubmit click event must rebind your data or in the page_load  before you access the controls

Comment: @Computer: add the above code in **QuestionButton_Click** event and after the `Repeater.DataBind();` line